# Is Visual Studio 2005 compatible with windows 8.1 64 bit?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, compatibility

I haven't tried installing it either on windows 8.

I need to modify a program which uses a crystal report 2005 (w/c i think is included on the vs2005 professional installer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work just fine after installing the required service packs and patches:

- Visual Studio 2005
- [Visual Studio 2005 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5553)
- [Visual Studio 2005 Update
  for Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7524)

If you are [connecting to TFS to get the sources, you might need to install more, see this blog post for details](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html).

Comment: Just confirming as of Dec 2014 these links still work and will allow you to install VS2005 on Windows 8.1 (x64). Make sure that you right-click the install files and "Run as Administrator". The 'Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite Service Pack 1' covers both VS2005 Standard and VS2005 Professional.